# NuGet lib folder content not included in package

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, dll, nuget

### Situation:

- Class library called `IMS.General.LabelWriter.csproj`
- Project **LabelWriter** references third party assemblies (*.dll)
- Third party assemblies are inside the *lib* folder in the project root:
  [image]
- The **.dlls** have their *Build Action* set to *None* in the Properties panel
- NuSpec file looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>$author$</authors>
    <owners>$author$</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>$description$</description>
    <copyright>Copyright 2015</copyright>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

- We execute this command:
  `nuget pack IMS.General.LabelWriter.csproj -Build -Symbols -IncludeReferencedProjects -Prop Configuration=Release`
- [NuGet docs](http://docs.nuget.org/Create/NuSpec-Reference) specifies this for the `references` tag in a nuspec file:

> v1.5 Names of assemblies under lib that are added as project
>   references. If unspecified, all references in lib are added as project
>   references. When specifying a reference, only specify the name and not
>   the path inside the package.

### Problem:

The third party assemblies are **not** included in the nuget package!

### Question:

Is this a nuget bug? Or am I doing something wrong? Because nuget describes this that as a convention: to put dlls inside the lib folder.
**NOTE**: Providing an answer that I have to include the `<files>` tag inside the nuspec file is not an answer to my question.